# "Они надеЯтся" или "надеЮтся"?

Tags: орфография

Никак не могу запомнить. ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Надеяться"* - инфинитив. Они надеются. [Включай зрительную память и запоминай.](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)

Comment: Валентин, все-таки к незнакомому человеку прилично обращаться на "вы", а не на "ты". Не говоря уж о том, что он может оказаться в два раза старше Вас.
Администратор

Answer (score 2):

В инфинитиве надеЯться  Я - это глагольный *суффикс*. Все глаголы с таким  суффиксом относятся к первому спряжению. Поэтому *окончание* -ют. (Говоря о всех глаголах. я имею в виду все глаголы с безударным окончанием).